# ¿Se puede cambiar el tamaño de una columna en un GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, layout

La idea es que quede del tamaño del boton,se puede?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal en establecimiento de lugar de los componentes en un Frame es el uso de varios Panel, conjuntando a su vez la configuración de cada uno con un layout. Teniendo en cuenta también que el propio Frame puede tener su propio Layout.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, no sería raro encontrarse un Frame con un GridLayout, y en cada una de las celdas de ese GridLayoud un Panel distinto con su propio Layout.

No se muy bien cómo va el GridBagLayout pero por lo general, los layouts que organizan el contenedor en secciones, suelen almacenar 1 único elemento en cada sección del layout, ocupando dicha sección entera. Si esto no te sirve en el caso de un botón, tendrías que almacenar en esa sección un Panel con un botón. Y a ese panel darle una configuración propia de layout.